# pySpark list to dataframe

Tags: python, list, pyspark, set

My code below creates a dataframe from lists of columns from other dataframes. I'm getting an error when calling a list that is produce by a `set`. How can I treat that set of list, in order to add those columns to my dataframe?

Error produce by `+list(matchedList)`

```
#extract columns that need to be conform 
datasetMatched = dataset.select(selectedColumns +list(matchedList))
#display(datasetMatched)
```

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably happens due to shadowing the builtin `list` function. Make sure you didn't define any variable named `list` in your code.

Comment: good point. It also got fix after refreshing my cluster @Gabip